# HP CP1525n - Paper jams on multi-page documents

Tags: printer

I have HP Cp1525n color printer at home. I do not print a lot, maybe less than 500 pages a year.

Some time ago a strange problem appeared. The printer prints just fine when I need to print a single page, but always jams the subsequent sheet of paper when I need to print two or more. The same happens when I print two single-page documents one immediately after another.

The jam is real, not that the printer just says me so. I have to remove tray 2 (the lower one) and pull out a paper that is already half into the printer body.

The printer is out of warranty, so I'm trying to do everything I can at home before taking it to the lab. I went through steps mentioned in "Prevent paper jams" in the [manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01945700.pdf), but they did not help. I printed so-called "cleaning page", but it did not help - the paper jams still happen. Do you have any other advice?

Comment: The cleaning page didn't print? didn't jam? What no effect?  Have you searched for drivers?

Comment: It printed as expected, but did not help - the paper jams still happen. Edited the question to clarify that. Thanks!

Comment: [Open the manual](http://www.partsnow.com/docs/service-manuals/hp-color-laserjet-cp1525-service-manual.pdf), go through the problem solving steps for paper-jams (see page 95).  Then come back and list exactly what you tried, and what the results were.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I went through steps mentioned in "Prevent paper jams", but they did not help. I'll update the question.

Comment: Make sure that the printer's paper weight setting corresponds to thickness/weight of the paper you're using. Paper weight is measured in pounds per ream (500 sheets). 20 lbs. is generally the standard for everyday home/office use.

Comment: @PFitz It is the regular office paper, 80 gr/m2. The paper size/type in Settings is set to "A4 Plain", so it seems OK to me...

Comment: A4 plain refers to the paper size, not the thickness/density.

Comment: @PFitz Well, I just checked the HP printing preferences dialog - and paper type "plain" is the default among other various weight options (like 90gr, 96-110gr etc). So it should be OK also.

Comment: Does that match the paper you are using?

Comment: @PFitz Yes, it does...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

had the same problem and fixed it myself. 
The problem om my CP1525nw was the rubber on paper pickup roller.

Use the following procedure to rotate the roller into the position required to remove it:

- Open the Secondary Service menu by pressing and holding both the Left arrow and the Cancel button simultaneously.
- Use the arrow buttons to select Pick roller, and then press the OK button.
- Press the OK button again to confirm that you want the pick roller to rotate.
- Turn the power off (by taking out the power cord!).
- Release the two plastic locking tabs and remove the pickup roller.

You can either replace the complete paper pickup roller or change the rubber on the roller. To change the rubber,

- Release the small lock in the U-shape that is holding the rubber on the wheel.
- Rotate the rubber band 180 degrees so that the used part is put in the U-shape and the unused part is on the wheel.
- Put the lock in the U-Shape and put the roller back in the printer.

That fixed the issue!

You can also order a spare part of the paper pickup roller. Partnumber is CC430-67901.
Also check the CP1520 Service Manual for more details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Finally had time to deal with it and found the rubber completely dry. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If there's a message saying the 2nd service menu is blocked: log into the web UI, navigate to "System" -> "Product Security", clear the password fields and click the apply button (and confirmation).